# MS Word Quick Parts Document Properties Publish Date vs SharePoint 2013 library modified date

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, word, quick-parts

I have Googled to death the difference between the Quick Parts Publish Date and the SharePoint 2013 library modified date and publish date.  When a document is approved, the Quick Parts publish date is not updated with the date it was approved.  It is in the Header.  So, what is this piece of metadata?  How can I get the SharePoint published date and date modified in the word document?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the Sharepoint 'publish date' - is this a custom date field you have made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design, actually you need to add custom filed in SharePoint so that you can get the SharePoint published date and modified date in word document.